# Python API request to internal API with OKTA Authentication

Tags: python, python-requests, request, okta-api

I used to selenium for downloading special reports from webpage where I have to login. Webpage has integrated OKTA Authentication plugin . I find out that there would be better and more effective use internal API requests. So I tried find how to use request python library with creating session, but I am unsuccessful. I tried this code, but it ends with 400 error.

```
payload = {"password":"password","username":"username","options":{"warnBeforePasswordExpired": True,"multiOptionalFactorEnroll": True}}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://sso.johndeere.com/api/v1/authn', data=payload)
  
    r = s.get("requested_url")
    
    print(p)
```

I am unable get throw auth. Has anybody experience with breaking OKTA auth plugin using requests library?

Thanks
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Merry Christmas and Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Firstly, an HTTP error code of 400 error means one or more settings is wrong at the client side. You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).

You seem to be missing out important headers configuration. You need to set the `content-type` header correctly otherwise the destination server won't be able to process your data.

Also, as a bonus point. You need to format your payload into a valid JSON string before sending out the request too.

```
import requests
import json

# Setup proper headers
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
}

# Your body data here
payload = {"password":"password","username":"username","options":{"warnBeforePasswordExpired": True,"multiOptionalFactorEnroll": True}}
payload_json = json.dumps(payload) # Format it into a valid JSON str


with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://sso.johndeere.com/api/v1/authn', headers=headers, data=payload_json)

    r = s.get("requested_url")
    
    print(p.content)
```

Comment: What happens if there is MFA enabled on OKTA ?.